# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - at Client.<init>(Client.java:64) at Client.main(Client.java:105)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting this error message, and I've tried many different things to fix it. Can someone tell me what I have wrong?
I had "null" after every private variable or method declaration I have on the code, but I even took that off thinking it was the issue but it was not. I have searched for the reason why this might but happening to my code but no luck.

This is a client/server interaction. And the other parts such as Server and BankAccount have no issues.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at Client.(Client.java:64)

at Client.main(Client.java:105)

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Client 
{ 
// initialize socket and variables 
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream input;
private DataOutputStream output;

BufferedReader br;  
BankAccount testAccount = new BankAccount(1000.00);
double wAmount = 150.00;
double dAmount = 200.00;

String num = "0";

// constructor to put IP address and port 
public Client(String address, int port) 
{ 
    // establish a connection 
    try
    { 
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Connection Sucessful");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        //once connection is established, bring up banking options
        System.out.println("Bank Mode Activated");
        System.out.println("Enter the number choice of what you'd like to do:");
        System.out.println("1. Withdraw");
        System.out.println("2. Deposit");
        System.out.println("3. Check Balance");
        System.out.println("4. To end the program");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");

        // initializes input stream and takes input from terminal
        input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        // sends output to the socket
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unKnown) 
    { 
        System.out.println(unKnown); 
    } 
    catch(IOException except) 
    { 
        System.out.println(except); 
    }
    
    
    while(!num.equals("4")){
        try{
            num = br.readLine();  //LINE 64
            output.writeUTF(num);
            
        if(num.equals("1")){
            testAccount.withdraw(wAmount);
            System.out.println("This is the balance after this transaction: $" + testAccount.getBalance());
        }
        if(num.equals("2")){
            testAccount.deposit(dAmount);
            System.out.println("This is the balance after this transaction: $" + testAccount.getBalance());
        }
        if(num.equals("3")){
            System.out.println("This is your account balance: $" + testAccount.getBalance());
        }
        if(num.equals("4")){
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
            System.out.println("User is finished.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid. Please try again.");
        }
        } //end of try
        catch(IOException i){
            System.out.println(i); 
        }           
    }
    // close the connection 
    try
    { 
        input.close(); 
        output.close(); 
        socket.close(); 
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
       System.out.println(i); 
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5000); //LINE 105
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please clarify, maybe with some comment in your code, which is the line actual line you are seeing in the stacktrace, just by the line number it's hard to see.

Comment: `br` is never initialized. Also, don't catch exceptions and continue on as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `br` class member isn't initialized, and it's always null.

Consider

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...);
```

See [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for details